# Error in installation

Tags: installation, boot, windows

I had Windows 7 starter on my netbook. I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a bootable USB drive and used " Something Else" option during installation. I used the windows 7 partition by mistake and now I cant load Windows 7 from boot menu  . . All my media files are in windows 7  . please suggest me a way to uninstall ubuntu to get back to windows 7 starter with all my media files intact.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, you formatted the partition. Best you restore from backups.

Comment: Now it asks me to use Windows CD and "repair computer"

Comment: If you used your windows partition to install Ubuntu then windows is no long on your netbook. You will need to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

well you won't be able to recover all your data because you formatted the partition and overwrite it with ubuntu 12.04 you might be able to get back some of your files you can use PhotoRec http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec with this tool run in linux and install it; then open the bin file in a terminal and follow the steps that you will see while you're running the program and it will recover most of the files; be warned this will take a lot of time and also will create a lot of files even files that you might not want such as temp files of the programs you had in windows 7 if you want to avoid so make sure to ask the program to recover only the files you need and you won't be able to recover windows unless you reinstall it but that will make more overwriting and will cause the lose of more of your files so i wouldn't recommend you to do so not until you get your personal data anyway. good luck with it

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but did the system automatically create a system restore file? I know it's no comfort, but I stopped using partitioned HDD's since making a similar mistake! We did recover all the importnat stuff, but we were working with two windows versions.